# How to manually set order in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to count SUM of numbers highlighted in blue if the month is bigger or equal to M1 and smaller or equal to M2. Unfortunately excel thinks, that M10-M13 is in between M1 and M2. Any tips how can I manage to write my formula or somewhere change the default order in excel to do this properly?

[image: Formula]

Comment: The problem is you are storing data that represents dates as strings.  Excel doesn't know they should be dates, so compares them as strings, so `2022 M2*` is always > `2022 M1*`  (where `*` is 0 or more characters).  The fix is to store the data as actual dates (and use format to display them as you want) or failing that, use a leading 0 for single digit months.

Comment: Easiest would be to use proper months instead. Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use proper months, but I can add 0 in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `B5`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(5:5,MATCH(B2,4:4,0)):INDEX(5:5,MATCH(C2,4:4,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the setup, prefix the month number with a zero for January to September.

**2021 M1** would become **2021 M01**

Excel will treat the data as ordered from **2021 M01** to **2021 M12**.

If you don't have control over the setup, you can reformat the headings via a formula to insert a zero before the month number.

```
=IF(LEN(F4)=7,CONCAT(LEFT(F4,6),0,RIGHT(F4,1)),F4)
```

Then use the reformatted headings in your formula.

[image]